# js prints as text instead calculating

Tags: javascript, string, addition

if the quantity is taken in both the if statement as 1 from the input element
my below code alerts 300400 where it should alert 700 as sum.

---

```js
function validateCart() {
  var check = false;
  var bill="";
  if (document.getElementById("bbc").checked) {
    check = true;
    var price = 300;
    var quantity = document.getElementById("bbq").value;
    var total = price * quantity;
    bill += total;
  };
  if (document.getElementById("gbc").checked) {
    check = true;
    var price = 400;
    var quantity = document.getElementById("gbq").value;
    var total = price * quantity;
    bill += total;
  };
  if (!check) {
    alert("no item selected");
  } else {
    alert(bill);
  };
};
```

---

i cant figure out what mistake i have done.

Comment: As per the code given, The output would be `NaN`

Comment: yup and if i try var bill = "' ; i get 300700 instead of 700 ... wait let me update the question

Comment: The result you describe would happen if you initialized `var bill = ''`, since then you're doing string concatenation. Use `var bill = 0;` and it should work.

Comment: thanks it worked... silly mistakes ... -_-

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialize bill to 0 :

```
function validateCart() {
  var check = false;
  var bill = 0;
  if (document.getElementById("bbc").checked) {
    check = true;
    var price = 300;
    var quantity = document.getElementById("bbq").value;
    var total = price * quantity;
    bill += total;
  };
  if (document.getElementById("gbc").checked) {
    check = true;
    var price = 400;
    var quantity = document.getElementById("gbq").value;
    var total = price * quantity;
    bill += total;
  };
  if (!check) {
    alert("no item selected");
  } else {
    alert(bill);
  };
};
```